# Sellotape or Cellotape?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm wondering if it is  Sellotape or Cellotape, or anything else(Sello tape or cello tape). I'm talking about the general name of that roll of sticking tape.

Comment: The usual word is sellotape or scotch tape in AE.

Comment: "Scotch" is a company in the U.S., but in casual situations, people refer to any brand as "scotch tape."  In  formal writing, I would use "clear tape."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about trade marks, not the English language.

Comment: @Adam: "Scotch" is a *brand*, not a *company*. The *company* is 3M.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The brand name is *Sellotape*. It is commonly written *sellotape* in places where the name has become genericized (i.e., is no longer an exclusive trademark).

Note that not all parts of the English-speaking world use or understand this word; here in the U.S., we say *scotch tape* (which also originated as a brand name). In fact, I had never heard "sellotape" until a few years ago, when an Indian coworker used it, and I had to ask her what she meant by it. (That's also when I realized that the *Spello-tape* brand in the *Harry Potter* series of novels is a pun.)